# Посоветуйте хостинг c поддержкой Java

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat, hosting, jboss

Насколько вообще дороже хостинг для Java, чем для PHP или Node.JS?
Из популярных я нашел только что на Openshift и на Google firebase есть контейнеры сервлетов. Что подешевле? Если есть бесплатные, вообще супер.
VPS не вариант т.к. дорого, да и для моего простенького сайта не надо.
Сенкс.

Comment: 200 рублей в месяц за сервер на vscale сравнимо с большим количеством хостингов.

Comment: Я пользуюсь VPS от majordomo.ru, плачу что-то около 300-400 руб. в месяц, на мой взгляд - не дорого. Там хоть Java, хоть LAMP ставь, хоть всё сразу (что я и сделал)...

Answer (score 2):

[Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/) от IBM - простой и стабильный PaaS с очень неплохим интерфейсом,своим [git](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/git/) репозиторием (с возможностью доводить код онлайн), и кучей подключаемых сервисов и библиотек от IBM...Касательно цены  [сюда](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/pricing/) ,как видно не нагруженные стартапы,тестовые серверы - бесплатно. Да и региональные менеджеры активные постоянные опросы,приглашения на вебинары etc...